# Problem with unnecessary variable update when constructing a component

Tags: reactjs

The situation is as follows. In my application, I use a router, and pass information to it whether the user is identified or not, similar to the role of the administrator. The data is stored in the `auth context`, put there `auth hook`, and used in App.js. The entire code is below. The problem is that when I reload the page, I get redirected from any tab to the home page. This happens because of a momentary change in App.js when constructing the App component, the variables in the `useRoutes(isAuthenticated, admin)` function change to false and true(true - after identification) when the page is reloaded. I'm relatively new to React, and don't really understand how to solve this issue. All I want to achieve is to make sure that the variables don't change their values in the App by simply refreshing the page.

App.js

```
function App() {
  const { token, login, logout, admin } = useAuth()
  const isAuthenticated = !!token
  const routes = useRoutes(isAuthenticated, admin)  
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{
      token, login, logout, isAuthenticated, admin
    }}> 
      <Router>  
        <div className="app-container">
          {routes}
        </div>
      </Router>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

AuthContext.js

```
function noop() { }

export const AuthContext = createContext({
  token: null,
  login: noop,
  logout: noop,
  isAuthenticated: false,
  admin: false,
})
```

Auth.hook.js

```
const storageName = 'userData'

export const useAuth = () => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null)
  const [admin, setAdmin] = useState(false)
  const login = useCallback((jwtToken, isAdmin) => {
    setToken(jwtToken)
    setAdmin(isAdmin)
    localStorage.setItem(storageName, JSON.stringify({
      token: jwtToken,
      isAdmin: isAdmin,
    }))
  }, [])


  const logout = useCallback(() => {
    setToken(null)
    setAdmin(false)
    localStorage.removeItem(storageName)
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageName))

    if (data && data.token) {
      login(data.token, data.isAdmin) // <-- There some problem
    }
  }, [login])


  return { login, logout, token, admin }
}
```

Comment: use redux to keep your app hydrated, with initialState declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with a simple solution :)

All you need to do is just add 1 more variable `ready` in the `context` with a value of `false` . Then set it in `auth.hook.js` to `true` after login. And export it to `App.js` and use it like `if(ready){return "page"} else return <>Loading</>`.